# Impossible to get the value of an Usestate in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to have a blink cursor in a  ...

I wrote this code, but impossible for me to understand why it's not working.

```
const [cursor,setCursor]=useState<string>("");

function blink(){

    if(cursor == '|'){
        setCursor("")
    }
    else{
        setCursor("|")
    }
    setTimeout(function(){ blink()}, 1000);
}


useEffect(() => {
    blink();
   }, []);


    return (
        <div>
            <span>{text}</span><span>{cursor}</span>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function blink(){
    if(cursor == '|'){
        setCursor("")
    }
    else{
        setCursor("|")
    }
}

useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(blink, 1000); // <- move setTimeout to here
}, [cursor]);  // <- and you need to pass cursor as a dep
```

Comment: I tried ... don't really work for me :'( I have this error : index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Comment: My bad, I moved the SetTimeout. Now it's working ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you wanted this:

```
const [cursor, setCursor] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const handle = setInterval(() => {
    setCursor(oldCursor => oldCursor === '|' ? '' : '|');
  }, 1000);

  return () => {
    clearInterval(handle);
  };
}, [setCursor]);

return (
  <div>
    <span>{text}</span><span>{cursor}</span>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: This solution works. However, I must point out passing in `setCursor` is pointless cus it’s always the same function ref.

Comment: @hackape I'm aware that `setCursor` is memoized, but it's better in my opinion to be explicit about dependencies, because it communicates intent better, and also the lint rule for rules of hooks required it to be passed, at least in early versions. I haven't checked recently if the linter now recognizes exceptions like `setState` callbacks yet.